# how many snacks is or how many snacks are...?

Tags: plural-forms

On ITV (britist tv channel) I have seen it used like this. Also in the following link I have seen it used that way, too.

[image: howmanysnacks]http://syvnews.com/lifestyles/columns/how-many-snacks-is-too-many/article_764dd4d0-20a1-59fd-8201-2527ed17c49e.html

How many snacks is normal?

This confuses me, because we learnt at school that "how many+noun" should be followed by "are" if the noun is countable.

And I checked in the dictionaries. The noun "snack" is a countable noun. So, then it should have been "how many snacks are...." not "how many snacks is..?

Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: I think that the writer regards 'many snacks' as a singular group. And the whole sentence would be 'How many snacks is too many (snacks)? It expresses 'one-to-one correspondence.' Don't trust my comment; I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

When time, distance, money, and weight are considered as collective units of measure, they are considered singular because they're collective. And therefore the question *'How many snacks **is** too many'* would be answered with a collective unit of measure("-50 grams of snack **is** too many."), which would mean 'is' instead of 'are', because it's collective. Here are some other examples:

Four hundred *snacks* **is** more than my extended family of five weighs.

Three hours **is** a long time.

Fifty kilometers **is** too far to walk.

Five thousand dollars **is** too much for that ratty old fur coat.

However, when the units are considered as separate entities, they're considered plural:

"Many hours **are** lost in arguing over even obvious errors." (Kris's example)

**Those** last five kilometers **were** killers, each for a different reason: crocodiles, mosquitoes, rattlesnakes, robbers, and army ants.

There **are** fifty silver dollars in the piggy bank. (There are 50 **coins**....)
The last three kilograms **were** lost at a rate of one per week instead of one per day. (Separate units of weight)

Just remember that collective means whole and separate means some part of the whole.